# Por que meu Service sobrecarrega o aparelho?

Tags: android, android-studio

Estou escrevendo um aplicativo que possui um Service cujo papel se consiste em tirar screenshots em intervalos de 15 segundos, usando um AsyncTask. Esse serviço, no entanto, sobrecarrega meu aparelho de tal maneira que, após alguns segundos, o deixa tão lento que até mesmo impossibilita seu uso. Não faço ideia do porquê. A definição de um handler para o OnImageAvailable do ImageReader dentro de um loop no AsyncTask me incomoda um pouco, suspeito que tenha algo a ver com o problema em questão. Como estou entrando nessa área do Android agora, estou bem desnorteado.

Abaixo está o código do meu service.

```
public class SSService extends Service {

    Handler handler;
    MediaProjection mp;
    MediaProjectionManager mpm;
    Intent mp_data;
    int mp_result_code;

    WindowManager wm;
    Display display;
    DisplayMetrics metrics;
    Point size;
    int mWidth;
    int mHeight;
    int mDensity;

    ImageReader mImageReader;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        handler = new Handler();
        Bundle bd = intent.getExtras();
        mpm = (MediaProjectionManager) getSystemService(MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);
        mp_data = bd.getParcelable("DATA");
        mp_result_code = bd.getInt("RESULT_CODE");

        wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
        metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        display.getMetrics(metrics);
        size = new Point();
        display.getRealSize(size);
        mWidth = size.x;
        mHeight = size.y;
        mDensity = metrics.densityDpi;

        mp = mpm.getMediaProjection(mp_result_code, mp_data);

        SCS s = new SCS();
        s.execute();

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    private void saveScreenshot(Bitmap bmp) {
        Date now = new Date();
        android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_hh:mm:ss", now);
        Log.i("DIB", "Salvando print...");
        try {
            // image naming and path  to include sd card  appending name you choose for file
            String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/vagdomScreenshots/" + now + ".jpg";

            File imageFile = new File(mPath);

            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
            int quality = 100;
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outputStream);
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();

        } catch (Throwable e) {
            // Several error may come out with file handling or DOM
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public class SCS extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(15000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                mImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(mWidth, mHeight, PixelFormat.RGBA_8888, 2);
                mp.createVirtualDisplay("screen-mirror", mWidth, mHeight, mDensity, DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_OWN_CONTENT_ONLY | DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_PUBLIC, mImageReader.getSurface(), null, null);

                mImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {

                        Image.Plane[] plane = reader.acquireLatestImage().getPlanes();
                        ByteBuffer bbuff = plane[0].getBuffer();

                        int pixelStride = plane[0].getPixelStride();
                        int rowStride = plane[0].getRowStride();
                        int rowPadding = rowStride - pixelStride * metrics.widthPixels;

                        Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(metrics.widthPixels + (int) ((float) rowPadding / (float) pixelStride), metrics.heightPixels, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
                        bmp.copyPixelsFromBuffer(bbuff);

                        reader.close();

                        saveScreenshot(bmp);
                    }
                }, handler);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Essa abordagem é errada. Em vez de tentar pô-la a "funcionar" use o WorkManager.

Answer (score 3):

Sem poder testar não é fácil saber a verdadeira causa.
No entanto, analisando o código disponibilizado, encontro vários problemas que podem justificar esse comportamento.

Da forma como está, devido ao `while(true){}`, a AsyncTask roda eternamente.

Um serviço pode ser destruído e posteriormente reiniciado pelo sistema.
Ao ser destruído e a AsyncTask não sendo parada ela continuará rodando.
Toda a vez que o serviço é reiniciado, outra AsyncTask é criada e iniciada.

Com o decorrer do tempo, o destruir/reiniciar do serviço pode acontecer várias vezes, mais AsyncTask's ficam rodando tornando o sistema cada vez mais lento.

Eventualmente, poderá estar a acontecer algum vazamento de memória(*memory leak*). Por exemplo, é usado um `try/catch` no uso de um OutputStream que não é fechado caso ocorra um erro.

Para a execução de tarefas agendadas, o Android disponibiliza soluções como o [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms) e [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIneau--Xr4wIVhUPTCh0q2gytEAAYASAAEgJMaPD_BwE).
Elas são geridas pelo sistema de forma a minimizar o seu impacto na performance geral do dispositivo.